# How to make (focused on modeling) burnt wood

Tags: modeling

For my art lesson I want to use blender to create burnt down Letters. I know how to texture it but I don't have an idea how I should model it. The idea is that the shape is still visible but the has a rough/deformed surface. Like a piece of wood that burnt but didn't break (like a matchstick?). I don't know how I could describe it better.

Example look:[image: Burned wood]

Comment: This is sort of a tutorial request.

Comment: You can handle this simply by sculpting.

Comment: The problem is that I suck at sculpting (hopefully only until I get my tablet). Well from nothing comes nothing, I'll just try every possibility I have, thx

Answer (score 3):

You can create a burnt wood look by sculpting. Disclaimer: I am not very good at sculpting

[image]

Here is how I did it:

1. First add a cube and scale it to the dimensions of the wood plank.
2. Add enough edge loops so that all polygons look square

   [image]
3. Subdivide the mesh in edit mode to a point where the square are about the size of the detail you want.

   [image]
4. Add a displacement modifier.

   [image]
5. Switch to sculpt mode and use the clay stripes brush

   [image]
6. Repeat until happy.

Answer (score 0):

As a strting point you could [*Subdivide*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Subdivide)  <kbd>W</kbd>  a scaled cube and adjust the number of cuts and add fractal randomness.

[image]

Comment: that's a great idea, the main problem with this one is that I would (mostly) evenly distributed vertices over my mesh. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem you're talking about is. If you meant to say "I WANT (mostly) evenly distributed vertices," you can still get that with this process. If your verts are evenly distributed before you subdivide, then they will still be evenly distributed after you subdivide.